# in Fabricjs, Freedrawing doesn't make a mark when called within mousedown

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In `fabricjs`, I want the user to select free drawing mode with a mouse click, but surprisingly the following code doesn't work (the cursor does change to 'cross hairs' after mousedown, but moving the mouse does not create a line on the canvas, and the resulting path object on mouse up is empty).  How can I achieve this, i.e. entering free drawing node on a mouse click?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById('canvasId'))
canvas.on('mouse:down', ()=>{
  console.log('mousedown')
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true
})
canvas.on('mouse:up', ()=>{
  console.log('mouseup')
 canvas.isDrawingMode = false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

replace 'mouse:down' by 'mousedown'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).